# Уникален ли в рамках процесса дескриптор сокета?

Tags: c++, winapi

Уникален ли в рамках процесса дескриптор сокета (`SOCKET`), возвращаемый функциями создания сокета (`socket()`, `accept()`)?

Интересует официальный пруф (ссылка на MSDN, или стандарт, или что-то похожее)

Comment: Уникален (но не запрещено двум сокетом на один адрес+порт коннектится)

Comment: А как вы себе представляете ситуацию, когда дескриптор сокета не уникален в рамках процесса? Вот вызвали вы `send`, передав ему дескриптор сокета, как эта функция будет различать, который из двух неуникальных сокетов подразумевался? Другой вопрос, что значения этих дескрипторов могут быть переиспользованы после закрытия.

Comment: А это интересный вопрос, потому что на MSDN не указано об уникальности сокета. Можно посмотреть на MSDN на других языках, порой бывают разногласия в описании. Сам для защиты в тендере использовал однажды русскую MSDN, хотя в английской версии была другая информация

Comment: Я разшифровывал socket на IDA - он представляет собой стандарные похожие на LocalAlloc  структура (несколько байт), кототорая обвёрнута вокруг "источника". Источник - в каком-то % случаев - файловый дескриптор драйвера, доступ к которому осуществляется через DeviceIoControl.

Comment: @VTT, тут вопрос в пруфах, которые необходимо предоставить в документации к ПО, по логике понятно, что дескриптор должен быть уникальным. У меня есть информация о дескрипторах в linux, где подробно расписано как они выдаются, как нумеруются, как переиспользуются и т.д. Хотелось бы такую же информацию и для windows из подтвержденного источника.